# Why is "Unstoppable Force" better than "Anti-tank Gun Production I"?

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

Two Intel Bulletin Slot upgrades in Company of Heroes 2 are Unstoppable Force:

[image]

> Pak43 Anti-Tank Guns build 10% faster.

and Anti-tank Gun Produciton I:
[image]

> Pak40, Pak43 and ZiS-3 Field Guns build 10% faster

Seems like Anti-tank Gun Production I is the clear winner here, so why is Unstoppable force listed as uncommon while Anti-tank Gun Production I is listed as common?

Answer (score 1):

Rarity doesn't always equal better perks. Typically, the rarer the bulletin, the more specialized it is. The reason for this is that if you were really in Pak43s, say; then you could have both Production I and Unstoppable Force in your roster at the same time, thereby granting you a 20% faster build time for Pak43s.

Hope that helps, and have a great day!